# How to implement events that unsubscribe when the subscriber is no longer referenced?

Tags: c#, events, messaging, weak-references

I'm trying to implement a messaging system and I was just using regular .NET events but the problem was that the publisher lives longer than the subscriber and the publisher holds a reference to the subscriber and prevents the event from being unregistered.

I was looking in to weak events but there are so many different implementations of them and I was having trouble wrapping my brain around them. I want something simple.

Also, most of them don't immediately unregister the event once it holds no references. I'd like a system that would immediately unregister the event once the object had no more references or went out of scope.

I'm fine with not using the built in events syntactic sugar and instead using a public static class of sorts to facilitate the whole endeavor.

I would just like to be able to raise an event in one class that would call the methods of all those subscribed that would automatically unregister immediately after the subscriber is no longer in use.

Can this be done or does this already exist in the framework in some way?

Comment: See [Weak Event Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) (msdn) and [Weak Events in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29922/Weak-Events-in-C) (CodeProject)

Comment: `I was having trouble wrapping my brain around them.` We've all been there, and sometimes you just want to get stuff done without having to learn something new. However, it's almost always the right thing to do to learn that new thing. Short-term pain equals long-term gain.

Comment: "prevents the event from being unregistered". What is "the event"?

Comment: Would you be okay with null'ing the event?

Comment: Have you looked at [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

If we'll define a delegate:

```
public delegate void Callback (string s);
```

And if the publisher class holds an event:

```
public event Callback Notify;
```

Then, a subscriber constructor will contain the registration code, 
and its class will contain an "Update" method that will subscribe to the event:

```
   class Subscriber 
 {
     Publisher publisher;

     public Subscriber (Publisher publisher) 
     {
      this.publisher = publisher;
      publisher.Notify += Update;
     }

    public void Update(string subjectState) 
    {
     state = subjectState;
    }
 }
```

In order to change this subscriber to unregister from the event when it is going to die we need to implement a Finalizer for its class:

```
~Subscriber () 
 {
   if (publisher != null)
   {
     publisher.Notify -= Update;
   }
 }
```

This way we can be sure that the subscriber will no longer be registered to the event.
for more information on the 'Finalize' method please read this great [article from the 'MSDN' magazine on "Garbage Collection"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx).

Comment: Accessing another object from your finalizer is *not* a good idea - that object may no longer exist. It would be better to implement the disposable pattern and put the unregister call in the `true` disposal path.

Comment: I didn't recommend on accessing this object from its finalizer. the garbage collector will call this finalize method when this object will no longer be referenced. only the garbage collector knows when this object is no longer refernced.

Comment: You're accessing `publisher` in your finalizer. the `publisher` reference may no longer be valid in your finalizer - that object may itself have already been cleaned up.

Comment: the subscriber has a refernce to the publisher. so the publisher can't be cleaned up.

Comment: If this was the last subscriber (or is part of a *set* of subscribers that were "last"), and no other references to the publisher exist, then both the publisher and the subscribers will be finalized. There's no guarantee on what order this will occur in.

Comment: lets see, this time of garbage collection when the subscriber is the last one, it has a refernce to the publisher so the publisher will not be cleaned up. the subscriber will be on the finalization queue. the next time the subsriber's finalize method will be called and then the publisher will have no referrences to it.

Comment: That's not how the GC works. In order for the GC to find all "alive" objects, it starts at roots (such things as stack variables, etc) and computes the transitive closure of objects reachable from those roots. If the subscriber is no longer "alive", then it's reference to the publisher will not be followed, and so the publisher will no longer be "alive" either. They'll both be put on the finalization queue during the *same* cycle, and in an indeterminate order.

Comment: See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688636/why-finalize-method-should-not-reference-any-other-objects)

Comment: ok i agree that if the publisher also implements a finalizer then we don't know the order of the cleaning. in the previous comment i meant that the publisher will not be cleaned up because there is a reference to it from the root - the subscriber is on the finalization queue - that's also a root. but still, i don't think the dispose pattern is relevant here  - maybe just check the reference for null before unregistering from its event in my answer.

Comment: No, the subscribers reference is *not* sufficient to keep the publisher alive. If it doesn't have a finalizer, it's "even more" gone - it may have been completely cleaned up. It is *not* safe to use *any* references to other managed objects from within your finalizer.

Comment: let's think of the best answer, what about checking for null before unregistering from the event? i believe the solution of dispose(true) will not be enough - because the owner class of the subscriber will be responsible now for unregistering the subscriber from the event. and what if it won't call the dispose on the subscriber?

Comment: If the publisher holds a delegate, the delegate will not be eligible for garbage collection or finalization until the publisher is.  If the delegate holds a reference to a subscriber, the subscriber will not be eligible for garbage collection or finalization until the delegate is.  Thus, a subscriber's `Finalize` method can't run until the publisher is eligible for garbage collection, at which point the subscription wouldn't matter.